# Migrating existing user details to new authentication system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, migration, authentication

Recently I have changed my authentication system to devise. I want to migrate my existing user data to this new system. Previous one was using SHA256 hash to save password. As I know this encryption is one way so in that case what will be the best way to migrate users data to new system. Devise support SHA512 encryption as well but not SHA256 as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply upping the hash size isn't buying much security. Please read up on intreated hashes and salting.

Traditionally, you upgrade a password upon the user changing their password. The type of password is either stored with the password (common format: `$type$salt$hashpassword`), or in an adjacent column, allowing you detect which algorithm to use.

Whether you force users to change their password is your choice.

Comment: is there any way to convert users existing password to new system. Old system was using sha256(Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(string)) and in new system im using sha512 algorithm

Comment: @Rishabh: I believe you should again look up what "one way" and "hash" means - the short answer is no. But also take notice about the need for salting.

Answer (score 0):

When a user enters their password (logs in), you can create a devise account for them automatically.  That's probably the easiest way to migrate.